# z-index issue on multiple LWC with picklist

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a Styling issue that I do not know how to solve..

I have to child LWC within a parent component
Each child component is a Data Table with an edit feature which give the ability to edit the data within the table

since some field are picklists it cause trouble when there a not a lot of rows in my table
Have a look at the gif.

Part of the code:

```
<div class="slds-scrollable_x  slds-var-m-left_x-small" style="height:100%">
                <table class="slds-table slds-table--edit slds-table--bordered slds-table_cell-buffer" style="table-layout:fixed;" >
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="">
                            <th class="columnsize" scope="col">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Name">Name</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="columnsize" scope="col">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Stage">Stage</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="columnsize" scope="col">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Deal type">Deal Type</div>
                            </th>
```

What would be the ideal way to display the picklist properly

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Regarding first thing, I'm not sure, because I can't see your html, but I'd guess you have `z-index` on second table, remove it and it should fix it.

Regarding second issue add `overflow: visible` so your picklist will should either way

Comment: Hi Thx you for your answer.

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: Hi Ytiq. I tried it. My issue is with a class I am using which is slds-scrollable. my component needs to allow scrolable-x but not Y. I added part of my code

Comment: I tried slds-scrollable_y_none but it does not exist